# PHP bind_params with null

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to bind params to a INSERT INTO MySQLi prepared statement if that variable exists, otherwise insert null.

This is what I have, but it is not working:

```
if (!empty($name)) {
    $result->bind_param('ss', $name, $url_friendly_name);
} else {
    $result->bind_param('ss', null, null);
}

if (!empty($description)) {
    $result->bind_param('s', $description);
} else {
    $result->bind_param('s', null);
}
```

Does anyone know of a better way of doing this or is there just a minor issue with my code. I am doing the above for each variable in the prepared statement.

Comment: Can you use an empty string there, e.g. `''` ?

Comment: Are you trying to leave a field out of the query if it is empty?

Comment: @tandu yeah if I can leave a field out, that would be work too. Do you have a better way of doing it?

Comment: You would have to conditionally construct the query .. I think that is what I would do though.  I don't use mysqli (that is what you're using, right?) So I don't know so much in this case..

Comment: Doing that would not allow me to use a prepared statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bind_param` works by reference.  That means that it takes a variable, then uses the value of that variable in `execute`.

`null` is not a variable.

Try setting a variable to `null` and then binding that variable instead.

(Also consider using PDO instead of mysqli, where the `execute` method can take a simple array and you can bypass wacky binding methodology of mysqli.)

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that you can't use bind_param twice, because the last statement will replace the first. Try to find a way to use bind_param just once.