# Preparing the query using mysql prepare

Tags: php, mysqli, prepare

I am preparing the query using mysqli prepare but this is giving an error
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use `near '?  ) AND    (  user_fullname ?  )'`

```
  $query="DELETE FROM table WHERE  (  quiz_answer ?  ) AND ( user_fullname ? )";
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);


  $stmt->bind_param('ss',array('IS NULL','IS NULL'));
  $stmt->execute();
```

Please help me finding the problem in query
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to bind parameters to MySQL syntax?

Comment: check http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: I want to use bind parameter to prevent the sql injection

Comment: The latter restriction is necessary because it would be impossible to determine the parameter type. It's not allowed to compare marker with NULL by ? IS NULL too. In general, parameters are legal only in Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements, and not in Data Definition Language (DDL) statements

Answer (score 0):

If we assume, that $answer and $fullname are your quiz_answer and user_fullname params.
This might work:

```
$answerString = 'IS NULL';
$userString = 'IS NULL';

if ( trim( $answer ) && $answer != 'null' ) $answerString = '= ?';
if ( trim( $user ) && $user != 'null') $userString = '= ?';

$query="DELETE FROM table WHERE  (  quiz_answer $answerString  ) AND ( user_fullname $userString )";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

if ( $answer && ! $fullname ) $stmt->bind_param('s',array($answer));
if ( $answer && $fullname ) $stmt->bind_param('ss',array($answer, $fullname));
if ( ! $answer && $fullname ) $stmt->bind_param('s',array($fullname));

$stmt->execute();
```

But i also suggest additional param validation to be executed before inserting them into sql query, even by parameter-binding.

Comment: I checked php.net there is clearly mentioned that we cant use NULL and IS NULL in bind params

Comment: It is strange, this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214574/php-bind-params-with-null shows that it should work.

Comment: Yeah, you should build your query string part-by-part then. If answer is empty then quiz_answer IS NULL, and if it is not empty then use param binding. I advice using PDO then, you can use named params there.